# How to use Android browser automation LOCALLY?

Tags: android, selenium, browser, automation

does anyone know how I could use SELENIUM or any other form of automation like selenium on Android locally? Which means, without using a server on a PC?

I don't know if, for example, I can use Javascript to run selenium as you can on PC, but on Android.

If anyone knows of any way to do this please help me out, thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Selendroid, it's a test automation framework which drives off the UI of Android native and hybrid applications (apps) and the mobile web. It can test the web page by using built in Android driver WebView.